# Mayavi - vtk.__helper.LinkError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, pip, mayavi

I want to install Mayavi. I installed all the requirements (Numpy, VTK version 5.1, PySide, wxPython, configobj, setuptools).
I have Windows7 64bit and python 2.7.6 32bit

When I type:

```
$ pip install mayavi
```

this is what i get:

```
Collecting mayavi
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\
urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is no
t available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may ca
use certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.r
eadthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached mayavi-4.4.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): apptools in c:\python2
7\lib\site-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traits in c:\python27\
lib\site-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitsui in c:\python2
7\lib\site-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): configobj in c:\python
27\lib\site-packages (from apptools->mayavi)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyface in c:\python27\
lib\site-packages (from traitsui->mayavi)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python27\lib
\site-packages (from configobj->apptools->mayavi)
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mayavi
  Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__fi
le__='c:\\users\\day\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uqi7fm\\mayavi\\setup.p
y';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))"
 bdist_wheel -d c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\tmpf4mpoupip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py",
line 471, in <module>
      **config
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in s
etup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 175, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py",
line 303, in run
      build_tvtk_classes_zip()
    File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py",
line 290, in build_tvtk_classes_zip
      gen_tvtk_classes_zip()
    File "tvtk\setup.py", line 46, in gen_tvtk_classes_zip
      from code_gen import TVTKGenerator
    File "tvtk\code_gen.py", line 10, in <module>
      import vtk
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
      __helper.refine_import_err('qvtk', 'vtkQtPython', exc)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__helper.py", line 32, in refine_imp
ort_err
      raise LinkError, str(exc)
  vtk.__helper.LinkError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be fou
nd.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mayavi
Failed to build mayavi
Installing collected packages: mayavi
  Running setup.py install for mayavi
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='c:\\users\\day\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uqi7fm\\may
avi\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\day\appdata
\local\temp\pip-9sftpq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-man
aged --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py"
, line 471, in <module>
        **config
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in
 setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", l
ine 57, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", l
ine 31, in setuptools_run
        return old_install_mod._install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py"
, line 303, in run
        build_tvtk_classes_zip()
      File "c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi\setup.py"
, line 290, in build_tvtk_classes_zip
        gen_tvtk_classes_zip()
      File "tvtk\setup.py", line 46, in gen_tvtk_classes_zip
        from code_gen import TVTKGenerator
      File "tvtk\code_gen.py", line 10, in <module>
        import vtk
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 139, in <module
>
        __helper.refine_import_err('qvtk', 'vtkQtPython', exc)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__helper.py", line 32, in refine_i
mport_err
        raise LinkError, str(exc)
    vtk.__helper.LinkError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be f
ound.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\day\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uqi7fm\\mayavi\\setup.py';exec(comp
ile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fi
le__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-9sftpq-r
ecord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed w
ith error code 1 in c:\users\day\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uqi7fm\mayavi
```

What am i doing wrong? I installed VTK properly, yet it reports an error. I tried uninstalling Python and installing Python(x,y) because it comes with VTK support, however there is a problem with it (I read on another forum that many people have reported that bug) so Python(x,y) is out of the option

Please help, I spent the last 16hours trying to install it, I am desperate

edit: it worked when I deleted Python 2.7.6 and installed Anaconda and typed "conda install mayavi" in cmd window. Using python on Windows is real pain

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: yes but in a different way. I simply deleted Python 2.7.6 , installed Anaconda, typed "conda install mayavi" and it worked